# expo-notification not showing notification from android device

Tags: android, react-native, expo, expo-notifications

I am using expo 42 in my project. I just exported the android folder by doing android-prebuild. After exporting the Android folder, I made the necessary arrangements for the notification in the android manifest. However, in android 12 and higher versions, the phone receives a notification, but the notification is not displayed on the device. Would you help me with this topic? Thanks.

what i tried was to export android folder in my expo project. I did this successfully. But now the notification does not appear on the device in android 12 and above versions. I also created a notification channel for this. But that didn't work for me Only android 12 and above have this problem.